# Measuring mains voltage with a 3.3V ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, impedance, crosstalk

I'm trying to simplify an existing circuit that measures mains voltage.  I have a 0-3.3V ADC and 5V and 3.3V DC power supplies (the negative sides of which are unavoidably tied together).  The part I'm trying to simplify is the voltage scaling and offsetting.  The current design uses a transformer, with one side of the secondary tied to 1.65V (generated with a voltage divider and a voltage follower).

So far what I've come up with is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffHBEv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This avoids the large, heavy and expensive transformers used in the current design.  Using 0.1% and 15ppm/degC resistors, I think this should give me reasonably good accuracy and temperature performance.  The op-amp in the diagram is a generic one; I'm actually using LM2902N.  This requires 1.5V head room on the positive rail, hence the use of the 5V supply.

There will be nine of these alongside each other, as I'm actually measuring three three-phase supplies.  They all have a common neutral.

I'm happy that the circuit gives me the gain and offset I want.  My question is whether there's anything that should be done to reduce cross-talk between
the nine measurements and anything I should add to improve noise rejection.

Also, could someone please confirm for me that the input impedance of this circuit is:

$$ Z = ( R1 // R2 ) // (C1 + R3 // R3) $$

and that I should select C2 for an appropriate roll-off frequency on this basis?

Comment: Before you go any further, figure out a design that provides safety isolation between the mains and your user.

Comment: Tom, besides the issue related to galvanic isolation, how would it be possible for anyone to recommend a value for \$C_2\$ without knowing your sample rate and your goals? Do you need a "mean value" for some reason? Or do you want a set of "instantaneous" measurements to do something with the shape of the mains voltage curve? And this is a 3-phase system besides? Need more info as well as isolation.

Comment: No matter how expensive the transformer is, it is almost certainly cheaper than paying for someone who was injured because you didn't want to protect them by using a transformer. And besides, at these power levels a transformer can be very small.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all.  There is no "user" as such here - it's a box that gets installed inside a locked cabinet & so isolation for safety is less of a concern.

Comment: @jonk Quite right, my apologies.  Target sample rate is 500Hz.